# Valor x input PHP

Tags: php, pdo

Código é este:

Pagina edita:

```
<?php
    $id = "";
    $DsStatus = "";

    if(!empty($_GET['id'])){
        $id = $_GET['id'];

        $results = $controller->listar($id);
        $DsStatus = $results->getst();
    }

    <form action="../controller/progPrecontrole.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return valid();">
        <input type="text" id="st" name="st" value="<?php echo $DsStatus; ?>"/>
    </form>
?>
```

Pagina tabela:

```
<?php
   foreach ($controller->ListaPorTipoB() as $objProg) {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><p><?php echo $objProg->getst(); ?></p></td>
        <td><a class="color" href="edita.php?id=<?php echo $objProg->getid();?>"><p>Alterar</p></a></td>
    </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Eu preciso que, se o valor do `$DsStatus` for um valor x no input, na coluna do status na pagina da tabela apareça caracteres especiais como este: ↓. Por exemplo, se no input for 10 mostra na coluna da tabela ↓, se for 11 mostra ↑ e assim vai.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça uma verificação com if/else e dê um echo com o código ascii do caractere: echo chr($cod_caractere).

Ex: echo chr(77); // Esse código exibe um "M".

Na tabela você tem essa linha :

```
<td><p><?php echo $objProg->getst(); ?></p></td>
```

Faz uma verificação assim:

```
<td><p><?php if($objProg->getst() == x) { echo chr($cod_ascii); } else { echo chr($outro_cod_ascii); } ?></p></td>
```

Mas para facilitar, é melhor fazer uma função que receba o $objProg->getst() como parâmetro e retorne o caractere correto.

Caso, por algum motivo, o caractere fique em branco, utilize decimal code

```
&#8593;
```

Função PHP que você pode usar:

```
<?php
function RetornarCarctere($x)
{
    if($x == 10)
    {
        return "&#8595;";
    }
    else if($x == 11)
    {
        return "&#8593;";
    }

    // E assim vai...

}
?>
```

Implementando a função na linha que falei, ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
<td><p><?php echo RetornarCarctere($objProg->getst()); ?></p></td>
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54285/discussion-on-answer-by-eduardo-h-m-garcia-valor-x-input-php)